# Can my database LDF and MDF files go into this directory?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, sql-server-2022, automation

Is there a way to determine, given a drive and a directory, if a CREATE DATABASE command would succeed?  There are basically two questions here.

1. How do you determine if a simple command like this will succeed?  Which directories will contain the mdf and ldf files, and can this be determined via query (say for a tool that creates databases and needs to provide a default directory that the user can choose to use)?

```
CREATE DATABASE v1rds
    ON PRIMARY (NAME=N'v1rds'     , FILENAME=N'v1rds.mdf')
    LOG ON     (NAME=N'v1rds_log' , FILENAME=N'v1rds_log.ldf')
```

2. If the user is allowed to enter a directory path into the database-creation tool, how can the directory path be validated?  The command like this works in SQL Server but not in AWS RDS SQL Server:

```
SELECT FILE_EXISTS, FILE_IS_A_DIRECTORY, PARENT_DIRECTORY_EXISTS
    FROM SYS.DM_OS_FILE_EXISTS('L:\LDF');
/****
Error message on AWS RDS SQL Server is:
    Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Line 1
    The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'dm_os_file_exists', database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema 'sys'.

    Completion time: 2024-02-20T14:29:26.6268208-05:00
****/
```

I do not know which permissions are required on the login that calls DM_OS_FILE_EXISTS.  Short of having to run the command as RDSA, which permissions or roles have to be granted to the login to make this work?

Thanks.

Comment: Nothing else other than to just try it. Default directory could be set to `SELECT CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultDataPath') AS nvarchar(260))`